# How can I sort a column alphabetically in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I'm beginning with R and I have a question.
I have this:

```
x <- data.frame(x0=c(1:10), x1=c("z", "a","a","a","a","a","c","b","b","b"))
```

So basically two columns. I want to sort alphabetically taking the entire row of the data frame.
So that 1 - z (both x0 and x1) appear at the end.

I've tried sort() but just managed to sort the column x1 and not both x0 and x1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` you can subset and `order`:

```
x[order(x$x1),]
   x0 x1
2   2  a
3   3  a
4   4  a
5   5  a
6   6  a
8   8  b
9   9  b
10 10  b
7   7  c
1   1  z
```

With `dplyr` you use `arrange`:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  arrange(x1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?